# What to do when a question had some votes to be on-topic on definition phase?

Tags: discussion, top-7

What to do when a question had some votes to be on-topic on definition phase? Respect the voters or redefine what is on-topic here?

Actual example: [How do I become a professional game designer?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/121/how-do-i-become-a-professional-game-designer) See [Are51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games/8141#8141) also.

If you think that question is off-topic, vote to close but don't down vote yet. We are learning here. Nobody knows what is a good question.

Comment: Yes, its a big question.  I feel we should be guided by the initial proposal, but not bound by it.

Comment: I think it would be better to open separate questions on meta for separate "types of questions". (This is how it typically goes on http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com.) So the first answer could be one meta question.

Comment: @Erik: Done. Thanks.

Comment: I thought you'd separated 'Are game design questions on-topic' out into a different question, based on @Erik's suggestion, but I couldn't find it. Started one here instead: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/236/are-game-design-questions-on-topic