# Are game design questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, top-7, on-topic

Are questions about new game design and development on topic?

Example: [How do I become a professional game designer?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/121/how-do-i-become-a-professional-game-designer)

They were voted as such in the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games/8141#8141).

(Note: To allow easier discussion, this question was separated out from '[What to do when a question had some votes to be on-topic on definition phase?'](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/what-to-do-when-a-question-had-some-votes-to-be-on-topic-on-definition-phase)).

Comment: Same question on the Game Development SE -http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/316/are-we-limited-to-video-game-development-here.

Answer (score 11):

In the absence of either an existing Stack Exchange site for board game development (like [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)) or a proposed and seriously committed to alternative on Area51 (unlike [Tabletop Game Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18588/tabletop-game-design)), I think they are very much on-topic - as long as they are tagged appropriately.